# Difference between Command (ICommand) and Click event

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

When should I use the `Command` and when to use the `Click` event?

F.e. if I have a `Button` in my UWP app what should I use?

Comment: command is binded with your viewmodel, while click event is written in code behind

Comment: The other bonus with command is that it has CanExecute so your UI can grey out the button when its not possible to perform the action. For best practise you should use the ICommand interface it makes your code much cleaner and easier to maintain in the long run, but if you are only going to have 1 button for a simple app then there's no real problem in just using the click event.

Comment: Another advantage of Command is that the same command can be bound to more than one UI element (e.g. you can bind the same command to a menu item and to a toolbar button).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> When should I use the Command and when to use the Click event?

Yours is a broad question and I would simply answer with: "**It depends**".
Because:

- The `Command` implements the `ICommand` interface and this means more code to add to your application but usually this won't change. Instead, the event handler doesn't require any interface implementation.
- For every command you want, you have to provide the code that will handle the click and the `CanExecute` logic, to say when the command can execute. This is not required in a simple event handler (like *MyButton_Click*). This means that, using a `Command`, you will have more control over the elements of your UI (the button won't execute anything if `CanExecute` is `false`).
- When you want to add a `Command`, you will bind it to your *DataContext* (the *ViewModel*, if you implement the MVVM pattern). Instead, when you add a simple event handler (like *MyButton_Click*), the code will be placed in your code-behind that is the logic behind your main window. In my opinion, this is best, as you'll have everything you need to modify in just one place (the *ViewModel*) instead of logic scattered everywhere in your project.

At the end of the day, it's up to you to use whatever suits you best, **considering also the requirements you have been given** (like: "Don't use event handlers" or "The Command is too advanced, let's just use something simple", etc.) **and/or other constraints in your project.**

Comment: nice answer in simple words

Comment: Good explanation. :)